# Earth as a grain of sand

Tags: earth, distances, observable-universe

If Earth was a grain of sand in Buenos Aires

[image]

in what point in this observable universe map would be LA be?

[image]

Comment: Of order only ten light years away.

Comment: LA and BA both at the center. I don't get the question, to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

The key to this kind of comparisons is to get a ratio. How much bigger is one number than the other?

From Buenos Aires to Los Angeles, there are nearly 10,000km. The size of a grain of sand varies a lot, but let's say it's a millimetre in diameter.

That's 4 orders of magnitude in the numbers themselves, then three orders of magnitude from there being a thousand metres in a kilometre, and three more from there being a thousand millimetres in a metre.

$=10^{10}$

This is how much larger the LA - Buenos Aires distance is than the diameter of that grain of sand. It is *also* how much larger the distance out in the universe is compared to the diameter of the Earth.

The Earth's diameter is a bit more than ten thousand kilometres, so after multiplication, we will end up with about $\approx 10^{14}km$. A light year is about $10^{13}km$, so we get out to the handful of closest stars.

Comment: https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/wikispeedia/wpcd/wp/s/Sand.htm provides some information of size for various types of sand.

Comment: From that, the 1mm sand would be "coarse sand"